# Qpid receive message by correlation id (using c++ application)

Tags: c++, qpid

Qpid offers responses to the received message. For parallel processing purposes we have multiple instances of the application that are listening to the same queue. The problem is that I would like that exactly the same instance receives the response. I believe that this can be done using correlation ids, but I cannot find an example how to do that with Qpid.

I searched the web and found discussion from 2009 (http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/get-message-by-correlationId-td3440876.html) where they aimed to add selectors shortly. This is probably the associated ticket (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-4558). There is finished subtask "Initial selector implementation", so I belive that this is implemented.

I was searching the API documentation and found methods getCorrelationId() and setCorrelationId(), but I cannot find an example how to filter the messages from queue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi. We have been using for this purpose "temporary queues" (and stuck with them). The client creates this temporary queue with auto delete flag and set "reply to" this temporary queue. Our application is designed that there isn't a big problem if messages from those temporary queues get lost.